# Visual Studio 2015 and uwp development - User-Mapped section error and CopyWin32Resources error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Continuing with some UWP development and 2 things keep happening with visual studio and I can't work out if its a VS2015 bug, the fact that I am deploying to a windows Mobile 10 device or something else.

Randomly when I try to build or deploy to my device I get either.

> Could not copy "obj\ARM\Debug\MyApp.exe" to "bin\ARM\Debug\MyApp.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
>
> Unable to copy file "obj\ARM\Debug\MyApp.exe" to "bin\ARM\Debug\MyApp.exe". The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.

or I get

> CopyWin32Resources failed with exit code 500

Seems to be random and I can't nail down what is causing either. Googling didn't really help. Some said `Anti-virus` but disabling mine did nothing. Some said it was something to do with `Visual Studio Achievements Extension` but I don't have it installed.

Anyone know the cause or a fix? Making development difficult when I can't deploy.

**UPDATE:** Ok so the first set of errors is more related to Windows 10 I think. When the error appears again I try to manually copy the file and when I do I receive similar error in explorer.

> error 0x800704c8: the requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.

Comment: You need to get your machine healthy again.  The 95.42% successful approach is to disable your anti-malware.  If it is Avast then get rid of it completely.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I have disabled the anti-virus and it did nothing.

Answer (score 5):

can you try those things:

- Close all other VS windows except one.
- Clean the project you works on.
- Try build project. If you get same errors, close all VS windows.
- Delete 'bin' and 'obj' folders.
- Open VS again and try building your project.

Then try deploying your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a bit of a hit and miss as I do some or all that you mention and sometimes it works. Just now I did as you said. I then rebuilt and deployed say 6 times with various changes. Just changed one line of code and now the `CopyWin32Resources` error has happened. Closed Visual studio and reopened and the error has gone away again.

Answer (score 0):

I know you might have found a fix already. But I had the same error after installing new emulators for my uwp application, after installing these emulators I seem to have gotten those errors. I thought uninstalling these emulators would be the fix, but was not. Now I run my program without restoring any missing packages and it seems to be the fix.

Comment: And also copied the my project into my C drive

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing the CopyWin32Resources Error on Windows, try uninstalling CbDefense (both Carbon Black Sensor and CB Defense Sensor 64bit). To much disbelief, this solution suggested by Microsoft resolved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem whenever I have my project in a folder that is synced by something like Dropbox. Pausing Dropbox always fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the problem. Moved the project out of the Visual Studio Project folder in My documents folder and into a projects folder on the C Drive. None of the errors have returned so I am guessing this is a windows 10 issue.

Comment: I would not agree with your guess.

Comment: Why is that? it has been 2 days now and I have had no problem. Anti-virus is fully enabled and I have more than one instance of VS running.